# Having trouble thinking of a formula for the following sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{1} ,\
\frac{2}{1}  ,\
\frac{4}{2} ,\
\frac{8}{6} ,\
\frac{16}{24}  ...\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq2A}$$

First term is when n=0.

Not sure if there is a pattern here. I can't seem to figure out a formula for this sequence

Comment: Have you tried figuring out sequences for the numerator and denominator separately?

Comment: @Jim still don't see anything, trying squares and subtraction. cant get anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $2^n/n!$?  It matches what you have so far.

Comment: wow u guys are geniuses, i would never have thought of that

Answer (score 3):

$\dfrac{2^n}{n!}\;$ seems to be an obvious solution (starting at $n=0$).

Comment: wow u guys are geniuses, i would never have thought of that